# thrust: sorting within a threadblock

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust

I am dispatching a kernel with around 5k blocks. At some point, we need to sort an array within each threadblock. If possible we would like to use a library like thrust. 
From the documentation I understand that how sort is executed in thrust depends on the specified `execution_policy`. However I don't understand if I can use `execution_policies` to specify that I would like to use the threads of my current block for sorting. Can someone explain or hint me towards a good documentation of execution policies and tell me if what I intend to do is feasible?

Comment: It is not. CUB has a block scope sort, however

Comment: If so that is a pitty. Can you tell me what `execution_policy` is used for and how it is used? Could not find any propper documentation on that.

Comment: https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__execution__policies.html

Comment: Hi, thanks. That's what I found as well but didn't find very conclusive. But thanks very much for your hints and your effort. its appreciated.

Comment: execution policy [slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6431-steven-dalton-advanced-thrust-programming.pdf)   [video](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/video/S6431.html)  to get the video to play, you may need to click in the center of the video window to get the controls to show up, then click the play button in the lower left

Comment: Thanks so much @RobertCrovella. This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that execution policies are basically a bridge design pattern that uses template specialization instead of inheritance to select the appropriate implementation of an algorithm while exposing a stable interface towards the user of the library and avoiding the overhead/necessity of virtual functions. Thank you [robert-crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella) for the great video.

As for the actual implementation of sorting within a threadblock in thrust, [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) is right. There simply is no implementation (currently?), I could not find anything in the source code.